# Flink - How many watermarks get injected in this bounded stream?

Tags: java, apache-flink, streaming, flink-streaming, watermark

In the below code:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> dataStream = env.fromElements(
            Tuple2.of("01", 1),
            Tuple2.of("02", 2),
            Tuple2.of("03", 3),
            Tuple2.of("04", 4),
            Tuple2.of("05", 5)
            ).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                                WatermarkStrategy.<Tuple2<String, Integer>>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                                        .withTimestampAssigner(
                                                (tuple,  ts) -> System.currentTimeMillis()));
  env.execute("dfjghf")

 env.execute("gghh");
```

---

flink - 1.17.1,
Java 11

---

1. 

How many watermarks will be injected in this bounded stream? Is it 5?

2)
How to print those watermark elements? Just for debugging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `forMonotonousTimestamps` is a periodic watermark generator, emitting watermarks every 200 msec (by default). This job isn't going to run long enough for that to ever happen. So I would expect just one watermark, at the end of the job. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984683/2000823) for more info about the end-of-job watermark.)
2. Watermarks can be inspected in the Flink web UI -- that's the easiest way to debug them. Otherwise you can access the current watermark through the context passed into the `processElement` and `onTimer` methods of a keyed process function.

Comment: How to emit 1 msec interval watermark?instead of a default 200 msec interval watermark

Comment: `env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(1);` @overexchange

Comment: You can also write a custom watermark strategy that emits a watermark with every event. But super-frequent watermarking puts a load on the runtime and reduces the throughput of meaningful events.